# Parsing HTTP header 'set-cookie' with HTTParty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-headers, session-cookies, setcookie, httparty

I'm using HTTParty for making HTTP requests and for using REST APIs. Now I want to re-use cookies set by a login page I called via POST.

```
class SomeImporter
  include HTTParty

  def self.login
    response = self.post('https://www.example.com/login', :query => {:user => 'myusername', :password => 'secret'})
    self.default_cookies.add_cookies(response.header['set-cookie'])
    self.get('https://www.example.com/protected')
  end
end
```

The cookies are not set correctly with this code.
How to parse the 'set-cookie' header given by HTTParty correctly and set the cookies for next request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually there is a single entry for each `Set-Cookie`within the HTTP header. HTTParty merges them in one single string as comma-separated list. But HTTParty doesn't split them by itself when adding them back to default cookies. You have to parse them by yourself.

It is possible to parse the 'set-cookie' with following method. Add it to your class:

```
# Parse the 'set-cookie' string
# @param [String] all_cookies_string
# @return [Hash]
def self.parse_set_cookie(all_cookies_string)
  cookies = Hash.new

  if all_cookies_string.present?
    # single cookies are devided with comma
    all_cookies_string.split(',').each {
      # @type [String] cookie_string
        |single_cookie_string|
      # parts of single cookie are seperated by semicolon; first part is key and value of this cookie
      # @type [String]
      cookie_part_string  = single_cookie_string.strip.split(';')[0]
      # remove whitespaces at beginning and end in place and split at '='
      # @type [Array]
      cookie_part         = cookie_part_string.strip.split('=')
      # @type [String]
      key                 = cookie_part[0]
      # @type [String]
      value               = cookie_part[1]

      # add cookie to Hash
      cookies[key] = value
    }
  end

  cookies
end
```

The cookies can be added to HTTParty for following requests by adjusting this line:

```
self.default_cookies.add_cookies(self.parse_set_cookie(response.header['set-cookie']))
```

Within `self.parse_set_cookie` the cookies are extracted only with name and value. You could extend it to get more details like `Path`, `Domain` and so on. See [RFC 2109](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt) (4.2.2 Set-Cookie Syntax) for more details.

Comment: There is date in the cookie such was `Wed,` you can't split by `,'

Comment: There is a defect in this implementation. It splits the cookie string on `=` however `=` is a a valid character in the cookie value. Indeed `=` is common in base 64 encoded strings. This leads to the `=` being stripped off the end of the value.

Answer (score 1):

```
def cookies_to_hash(acookies)
    vs = acookies.split(',')
    ak = Array.new
    # Avoiding break in expiry date comma
    vs.each_cons(2) do |v, vn|
        unless(vn.include?("="))
            ak << "#{v}#{vn}"
        else
            ak << v if(v.include?("="))
        end
    end
    # Cookies as array of hashes
    all_cookies = []
    ak.each do |each_cookie|
        ecookie = []
        each_cookie.split(';').each do |cookie_attr|
            ecookie << cookie_attr.split("=")
        end
        all_cookies << Hash[ecookie]
    end
    all_cookies
end
```

The above method will help you convert **set-cookies** in response headers into a valid array of hashes. Handled problems with additional commas on the expiry.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not handle the expire date

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @dineshspabu, I'm able to follow his pattern and add some modifications to handle expire date. Hope this help:

```
def cookies_to_hash(set_cookie)
  set_cookie = set_cookie.gsub(/Expires=[a-zA-Z]+,/) do |m|
    # replace , with #####
    m[0..-2] + "#####"
  end
  set_cookie = set_cookie.split(',')
  # Cookies as array of hashes
  all_cookies = []
  set_cookie.each do |each_cookie|
    ecookie = []
    each_cookie.strip.split(';').each do |cookie_attr|
      # replace ##### with , back
      ecookie << cookie_attr.split("=").map{|e| e.gsub(/#####/, ',') if e}
    end
    all_cookies << Hash[ecookie]
  end
  all_cookies
end
```